# How to write client side scripts for ajax call that outputs Json object

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, model-view-controller

when I create ajax calls - I usually ask for pure HTML.
but now, for several reason, **I need advice on how to build the table** (let's say of persons and their data) **when receiving Json object** - I know how to create a table in Javascript - **but since I am new to this concept of Json-from-server I want to do it the right way**

let's say my json is this:

```
[[name: foo, email:foo@bar.com ...][name:baz,...] ... []]
```

What is the right way to build a js to build a table for it. my guess it would go for something like:

```
var table = {
    init : function() {..}
    new : function(Json) {..} 
    delete : function(Json) {..}
}

var row = {
    init : function() {..}
    new : function(rowParam) {..}
}

var cell = { ... }
```

**My questions are:**

1. I walk in the dark trying to figure out if this is the right way - Is it?
2. Something smells here from MVC - Is it? How do I build it correctly with MVC pattern? assuming this table needs to be quite interactive (plenty of events and manipulations)
3. Something also smells from "there are js libraries that do these sort of things" - I have no idea where to start because it is hard to define for myself what is it that I am trying to do exactly.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to build a [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) GUI in a webpage? Please write a little story that describes what you want to do with that JSON.

Comment: I want to build (for example) a table that contains all the people that lives in my street. I ask the server to give me a JSON object that contains all these people and then I want to build an HTML table with all the data that came. I am asking how do I build the table with Javascript correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First, I need to correct your format of json. Since you are dealing with array of object format is

```
[
  { 
    propery: "some value", 
    property2: "some other value"
  },
   //.... more objects {} here
];
```

Before we dive in code, you should know that response from server comes as string so you need to "compile" it to javascript object(s). You can do that in 2 ways

1. Preferred way using `JSON.parse(someString);` method
2. ugly and less desirable is to use `eval` or `Function` methods like `var result=[]; eval("result=" + responseStringFromServer);`

Always use first aproach since its better and if you wont to know why please check [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)

Since you want to use your types (Table, Row and cell) you should know its useless since JSON is short of JavaScript Object Notation, in other words, once you do var `myArray= JSON.parse(responseFromServer);` myArray will be an javascript array which each item is Javascript object. If you don't need to know what is the underling type don't convert it your object(s)

Working example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/sEwM6/) 
And here is how it works

You need place holder in html for your data, lets say it looks like this:

```
<table id="personDataTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Lets say we got result from ajax like this

```
[
   {
       id: 1,
       firstName: "Peter",
       lastName: "Jhons"
   },
   {
       id: 2,
       firstName: "David",
       lastName: "Bowie"
   }
]
```

To draw data you can use this 3 methods

```
// This will iterate over each result in array (as you mentioned the javascript table)
function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // call method to draw each row
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    // create html table row
    var row = $("<tr />")
    // append it to HTML teable element
    $("#personDataTable").append(row); 
    // append each cell to row html element with data in it
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.id + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.firstName + "</td>"));
    row.append($("<td>" + rowData.lastName + "</td>"));
}
```

And finally, your ajax call (using jQuery of course)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        //... pass here any data you want to your server
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // since we are using jQuery, you don't need to parse response
        drawTable(data);
    }
});
```

And at the end of this post, you should know that there are many neath libraries there which can simplify this proces. Some are really ment to be used for complex situations, like BackboneJS and AngularJs .... and some are simple, like jQuery.template od jQuery.render, which are only template engines. It depends how complex your app is and how many "rendering" should happen in single page.

**Same as example abobe but using AngularJS**

Working example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjaric/pJ5BR/)

You will need page like this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>Example 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.1/angular-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
table {
  border: 1px solid #666;   
    width: 100%;
}
th {
  background: #f8f8f8; 
  font-weight: bold;    
    padding: 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Assign Controller to element, it will handle the "data scope" and events of ineer elements -->
<div ng-controller="PeopleCtrl">
     <!-- Example of attaching event handler to link click event -->
    <p>    Click <a ng-click="loadPeople()">here</a> to load data.</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- here is how to receptively render array of object using ng-repeat directive. Note that you have defined people attribute in $scope object, it is bound to this template below --> 
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{person.id}}</td> <!-- bind single attribute -->
        <td ng-template="{{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}"></td> <!-- binding 2 attributes to same element using ng-template directive -->
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// define your module (application)
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
// define controller responsible to get data and bind result to page
function PeopleCtrl($scope, $http) {

    $scope.people = []; //this will be used in page template above
    // event handler for link which you need to click in order to get data  
    $scope.loadPeople = function() {
        // change link to hit your server json
        var httpRequest = $http.get("/link/to/people.json");
        // on success of HTTP GET request above handle response and set new data
        httpRequest.success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.people = data;
        });

    };

}​
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working backwards with your questions, I'll answer #3 first.  You could look at a JavaScript library called [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/index) to do what you're looking to do, or maybe even [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php) if you need a lot of interaction with your table.  They're both jQuery plugins.

If you have a lot of events and manipulations going on, it sounds like you're looking at more of a MVVM approach, sort of like [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/), [Ember](http://emberjs.com/) or a number of other libraries out there.  But based on what you provided, I'm not sure if you're following a MVC approach or not.

Lastly, based on the skeleton JS you provided, it seems like a decent approach.  You're breaking out your table, rows and cells into separate functions, where I assume you'll handle events raised by your user's interaction with the table.  I'm also assuming you'll have `table` referencing `row` and `row` referencing `cell`.  It may be a nit-pick, but you probably want to define them in the opposite direction so that JSLint doesn't complain.

I hope this helps.  I can further elaborate if you have questions.  Good luck!

Comment: that gives me a lot of stuff to research and that was what I was looking for. thanks a lot!